# Validating one datetime to be later than another

Tags: ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try and validate two Datetime attributes in their model, I get the following:

> undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass

It highlights my function

```
def validate_timings
    if (startDate > endDate)
        errors[:base] << "Start Time must be less than End Time"
    end
end
```

and in particular the use of '>'

I think it may be the way I'm handleing the dates, but I'm not sure. This is how the dates are passed:

```
"startDate(1i)"=>"2013",
 "startDate(2i)"=>"12",
 "startDate(3i)"=>"18",
 "startDate(4i)"=>"10",
 "startDate(5i)"=>"24",
 "endDate(1i)"=>"2013",
 "endDate(2i)"=>"12",
 "endDate(3i)"=>"18",
 "endDate(4i)"=>"11",
 "endDate(5i)"=>"24",
```

P.S I know my naming conventions are incorrect, I will change them in the next migration.

UPDATE: Here is my full Model

```
   class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :car
    belongs_to :service
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :car

    attr_accessor :period, :frequency, :commit_button

    validates_presence_of :car_id, :service_id, :startDate, :endDate
    validate :validate_timings


    def validate_timings
        p startDate, endDate
        if (startDate > endDate)
            errors[:base] << "Start Time must be less than End Time"
        end
    end

    def update_appointments(appointments, appointment)
        appointments.each do |e|
            begin
                st, et = e.startDate, e.endDate
            e.attributes = appointment

            nst = DateTime.parse("#{e.startDate.hour}:#{e.startDate.min}:#{e.startDate.sec}, #{st.day}-#{st.month}-#{st.year}")
            net = DateTime.parse("#{e.end.hour}:#{e.end.min}:#{e.end.sec}, #{et.day}-#{et.month}-#{et.year}")
            #puts "#{nst}           :::::::::          #{net}"
            rescue
            nst = net = nil
        end
        if nst and net
            #          e.attributes = appointment
            e.startDate, e.endDate = nst, net


           e.save
        end
    end

  end
end
```

Comment: Are you sure `startDate` or `endDate` cannot be `nil`?

Comment: validates_presence_of :car_id, :service_id, :startDate, :endDate

Comment: There is nothing wrong with code shown in the method. The fault is elsewhere and result of it is that one of `startDate` or `endDate` is nil. Probably `endDate`, and something is trying to coerce it from `nil` for the comparison. For a crude debug validation of this try adding `p startDate, endDate` at the top of the method.

Comment: Yeh, it looks like no values are being passed. I assumed they were passing correctly due to the 'Request' Parameters section in the error.

Comment: it seems that `endDate` is `nil`, which has no method `to_datetime`, you have to debug, where the `endDate` becomes `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

Your comparison operator is correct. However, when you call this operator on a datetime object, it tries to convert the right-hand object into another datetime object.

i.e : "Time.now < nil"  will return :
"NoMethodError: undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass" instead of an invalid date error.

So in your case, the error you get means that you don't have a proper datetime **endDate** when you try to compare them.

It seems that you call your validation method before the object of your model has had the time to load its endDate value.

Comment: Thanks, my model calls the validate_timings function last, however, i'm calling the form in Ajax, so perhaps my problem lies there.

Comment: I can't see why Ajax could cause such a problem. Could we see more of your model code ?

Comment: Thanks, I have added the full Model to my question.

Comment: And you only save your appointments with the update_appointments method ?

Answer (score 0):

1. use start_date, end_date for property names. this is convention
2. you can use if like if start_date && end_date && end_date > start_date .....
3. do not use "and". use &&

Comment: Thanks, as mentioned, naming conventions are going to be adhered to in the next migration. I don't believe any of these suggestions will solve my issue?